# Make command using default target name 'Makefile'

Tags: makefile

Why is the following makefile using `Makefile` target?

Makefile1:
Initially I have the following makefile which worked as expected when invoked as make *abc xyz -s*.

```
%::
echo $@
```

I would get

```
abc
xyz
```

Makefile2:
Now after adding an empty rule named test.

```
%:: test
     echo $@
test:
```

the following invocation

```
make abc xyz -s
```

results in

```
Makefile
abc
xyz
```

Why am I getting *Makefile* as my output even though I am giving only `abc` and `xyz` as targets? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because make always tries to rebuild the build files before building the actual targets. If it finds a rule for Makefile and if it is out-of-date, it will be rebuilt *and reloaded* and the requested targets will be built according to the new makefile. This is a feature so that if the build-files are themselves generated (rather common with autotools, cmake and similar), it won't use stale build instructions.

For more details see [GNU Make Manual section 3.5](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles)

In the specific examples above the rule has target `%` and that matches absolutely anything, including `Makefile`. So make will find it as rule for remaking makefile and will evaluate it.

Now in the first case `Makefile` exists and is newer than all of it's dependencies trivially because there are none and none of it's dependencies need to be remade also because there are none. So make will conclude that Makefile does not need to be remade.

In the second case however `Makefile` exists, but it's dependency `test` needs to be remade. So make runs the (empty) rule and than comes back and runs the rule for `Makefile`. Because make does not check the timestamps after making dependencies. It simply assumes that when it remade them, the dependent targets need to be remade as well.

Comment: +1 indeed.  The OP should use the `-d` flag to see what's really going on.

Comment: Your explanation is correct, But could you please elaborate a bit in the context of my example. What do you mean by "if it finds a rule for Makefile".